# PHP get value from an array

Tags: php, json, curl, html-entities, whmcs

I have this PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$jsondata = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) 
    die("Connection Error: ".curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($jsondata);
echo "\nResponse: ".htmlentities($jsondata)."\n\nArray: ".print_r($arr,true);
```

Which outputs:

```
Response: {"result":"success","clientid":83} Array: 
stdClass Object ( [result] => success     [clientid] => 83 )
```

I want to grab the value `83` stored in the variable called `$clientid`.

But I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are confusing a PHP object with a PHP array.**

You should be doing this:  `echo $arr->clientid;`

**Example 1, access a value of an object like this:**

```
<?php 
  $jsondata = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}';
  $arr = json_decode($jsondata);

  echo gettype($arr);
  echo $arr->firstName;
?>
```

This prints:

```
object
John
```

**Example 2, access a value of an array like this:**

```
<?php 
  $yarr = array(5,6,7);
  echo $yarr[0];
?>
```

This prints:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is assuming json_decode returns an array.

```
$arr = json_decode($jsondata);
```

Will set up $arr as an object. If you wanted to access it as an array, you can do this:

```
$arr = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);
```

The extra parameter on the end tells json_decode to return an array instead of an object. Then you could do:

```
echo $arr["clientid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try `echo $arr["clientid"]` to get data from array

Comment: Gives an error ~ PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: My bad, saw "Array" on your output.